# Нужна идея по реализации функции в боте знакомств Python aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

*Приветствую уважаемые!* Обращаюсь к всевышним (вам) за советом. Пишу подобие на leomatchbot (ДайВинчик) на aiogram 3. Буду использовать как основную БД PostgreSQL, для тестов на этапе написания использую SQLite3. Питон 3.10 (я здесь впервые поэтому если много воды прошу принять и сказать в чем ошибаюсь)

**Уже сделано:** этап регистрации и создания анкеты, меню из 4 функций.

**В чем нужна помощь:** процесс просмотра анкет.

Есть мысли о том как реализовать процесс, но очень хотел бы для начала услышать мнение со стороны.
В БД хранится идентификатор пользователя то есть user_id и как мы знаем он уникальный, и еще информация про пользователя. С показом анкет проблем нет, тут решу, ***вопрос в том как и куда лучше  сохранять анкеты которые уже пролистал пользователь?(важно делать это именно для одного пользователя так как их будет много). Фильтрация идет по полу и возрасту, то есть пользователю показывает анкеты в соответствии с параметрами которые он указал при регистрации. И еще думаю как лучше сделать, с БД, если на каждое действие делать запрос будет очень много ресурсов тратиться, можно ли при запуске будет вытащить все данные и анкеты в словарь в котором будет вся инфа о пользователях чтоб каждый раз к БД не обращаться?***

Заранее спасибо за ваши идеи, уважаемые!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.